# Dynamically add row to Table Layout Panel

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

I am trying to add rows with textboxes dynamically to a Table Layout Panel, and the code I have here adds the row, but the spacing is off. When it adds the row it is smaller than the row before. Any ideas on how to add a row that is also formatted the same as the previous? Thanks.

```
    int A = 1;
    public TextBox AddNewTextBox()
    {
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        this.Controls.Add(txt);
        txt.Top = A * 28;
        txt.Left = 15;
        txt.Text = " ";
        A = A + 1;
        return txt;

    }
    public void DeleteTextBox()
    {
        if (A >= 2)
        {
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.RemoveAt(A);
            A--;
        }
    }
    private void AddRowBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount++;

        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 28.57143F));
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(AddNewTextBox());
        if(A >= 10)
        {
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new Size((282),(207*2)) ;
        }
    }
    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        DeleteTextBox();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the **AutoSize** property of tableLayoutPanel to **true** or Use following code on form Load or inside the constructor of form

```
tableLayoutPanel1.AutoSize = true;
```